# NuGet feeds vs. NuGet Server vs. NuGet Gallery

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

we are a small developer team and we want to start using our Libraries as NuGet packages. Now I have seen that we can create a NuGet feed or a NuGet Server or a NuGet Gallery.

Now we are not sure what's the difference and what's the rights decision for our small team.

Can someone please explain us that?

Thank you in forward!

Regards
Matthias

Comment: If your team is less than 6 you can use Package Management in Team Services for free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick breakdown:

Feed: Preferable if you want your packages to only be available to your team.  You can choose your audience.

Server: Packages are available to public through http protocall.

Gallery: Packages are hosted on an Internet server using the NuGet Gallery Project (github.com). NuGet Gallery provides user management and features such as an extensive web UI that allows searching and exploring packages from within the browser, similar to nuget.org.

Please read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)

Answer (score 6):

This is where you need to go

[Hosting your own NuGet feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/overview)

> - **Local feed**: Packages are simply placed on a suitable network file share, ideally using nuget init and nuget add to create a hierarchical
>     folder structure (NuGet 3.3+). For details, see [Local Feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds).
> - **NuGet.Server**: Packages are made available through a local HTTP server. For details, see [NuGet.Server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/nuget-server)
> - **NuGet Gallery**: Packages are hosted on an Internet server using the [NuGet Gallery Project](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery#build-and-run-the-gallery-in-arbitrary-number-easy-steps) (github.com). NuGet Gallery provides user
>     management and features such as an extensive web UI that allows
>     searching and exploring packages from within the browser, similar to
>     nuget.org.